# use @ControllerAdvice and @ExceptionHandler but still also allow for the default exception mapping

Tags: spring-mvc

When i use a `@ControllerAdvice` with the `@ExceptionHandler` annotation then none of the normal exception handling works anymore. All results in a HTML page with the title "HTTP Status 500 – Internal Server Error" and nothing is logged in the console.

I've created a simple `@ControllerAdvice` as below, when this didn't work as expected i started trying with the `basePackages` and extending from `ResponseEntityExceptionHandler`.

```
@ControllerAdvice(basePackages = "nl.xxxx.events")
public class EventExceptionHandler extends ResponseEntityExceptionHandler {
    private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(EventExceptionHandler.class);

    @ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND)
    @ExceptionHandler(EventNotFoundException.class)
    public void handlePersonNotFound(RuntimeException ex) {
        logger.error("error", ex);
    }
}
```

In the service i throw the exception using:

```
public Event findById(Long id) {
    return this.eventRepository.findById(id).orElseThrow(() -> new EventNotFoundException(id));
}
```

I've tried to compare the flow of code with and without `@ControllerAdvice` but there are numerous things that are different. For example without the `@ControllerAdvice` the value attribute of the `HttpEntityMethodProcessor` is set with the an object describing the exception. But with the `@ControllerAdvice` this attribute is always `null`.

I expected the code above to not interfere with the normal exception handling.

As a example i'd like to use the "could not initialize proxy - no Session" error because this is easy for me to reproduce.

Before i added the `@ControllerAdvice` spring gave the following json result:

```
{"timestamp":"2019-06-02T19:17:14.223+0000","status":500,"error":"Internal Server Error","message":"Could not write JSON: failed to lazily initialize a collection of role: (truncated)....","path":"/events/find"}
```

and with debug logging:

```
2019-06-02 21:18:29.723 DEBUG 1588 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : GET "/events/find?page=1&size=10", parameters={masked}
2019-06-02 21:18:29.724 DEBUG 1588 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping : Mapped to public org.springframework.data.domain.Page<nl.xxxx.events.Event> nl.xxxx.events.EventController.findPersons(java.lang.String,java.lang.Integer,java.lang.Integer)
2019-06-02 21:18:29.728 DEBUG 1588 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] m.m.a.RequestResponseBodyMethodProcessor : Using 'application/json', given [application/json, text/plain, */*] and supported [application/json, application/*+json, application/json, application/*+json]
2019-06-02 21:18:29.728 DEBUG 1588 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] m.m.a.RequestResponseBodyMethodProcessor : Writing [Page 1 of 19 containing nl.xxxx.events.Event instances]
2019-06-02 21:18:29.729  WARN 1588 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] .w.s.m.s.DefaultHandlerExceptionResolver : Resolved [org.springframework.http.converter.HttpMessageNotWritableException: Could not write JSON: failed to lazily initialize a collection of role: nl.xxxx.events.Event.schedule, could not initialize proxy - no Session; nested exception is com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException: failed to lazily initialize a collection of role: nl.xxxx.events.Event.schedule, could not initialize proxy - no Session (through reference chain: org.springframework.data.domain.PageImpl["content"]->java.util.Collections$UnmodifiableRandomAccessList[0]->nl.xxxx.events.Event["schedule"])]
2019-06-02 21:18:29.729 DEBUG 1588 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Completed 500 INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR
2019-06-02 21:18:29.729 DEBUG 1588 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : "ERROR" dispatch for GET "/error?page=1&size=10", parameters={masked}
2019-06-02 21:18:29.730 DEBUG 1588 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping : Mapped to public org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity<java.util.Map<java.lang.String, java.lang.Object>> org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.servlet.error.BasicErrorController.error(javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest)
2019-06-02 21:18:29.731 DEBUG 1588 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] o.s.w.s.m.m.a.HttpEntityMethodProcessor  : Using 'application/json', given [application/json, text/plain, */*] and supported [application/json, application/*+json, application/json, application/*+json]
2019-06-02 21:18:29.731 DEBUG 1588 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] o.s.w.s.m.m.a.HttpEntityMethodProcessor  : Writing [{timestamp=Sun Jun 02 21:18:29 CEST 2019, status=500, error=Internal Server Error, message=Could not (truncated)...]
2019-06-02 21:18:29.732 DEBUG 1588 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Exiting from "ERROR" dispatch, status 500
```

But now it returns:

```
<!doctype html><html lang="en"><head><title>HTTP Status 500 – Internal Server Error</title><style type="text/css">h1 {font-family:Tahoma,Arial,sans-serif;color:white;background-color:#525D76;font-size:22px;} h2 {font-family:Tahoma,Arial,sans-serif;color:white;background-color:#525D76;font-size:16px;} h3 {font-family:Tahoma,Arial,sans-serif;color:white;background-color:#525D76;font-size:14px;} body {font-family:Tahoma,Arial,sans-serif;color:black;background-color:white;} b {font-family:Tahoma,Arial,sans-serif;color:white;background-color:#525D76;} p {font-family:Tahoma,Arial,sans-serif;background:white;color:black;font-size:12px;} a {color:black;} a.name {color:black;} .line {height:1px;background-color:#525D76;border:none;}</style></head><body><h1>HTTP Status 500 – Internal Server Error</h1></body></html>
```

And with debug logging:

```
2019-06-02 21:20:33.682 DEBUG 22308 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : GET "/events/find?page=1&size=10", parameters={masked}
2019-06-02 21:20:33.688 DEBUG 22308 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping : Mapped to public org.springframework.data.domain.Page<nl.xxxx.events.Event> nl.xxxx.events.EventController.findPersons(java.lang.String,java.lang.Integer,java.lang.Integer)
2019-06-02 21:20:33.760  INFO 22308 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.h.h.i.QueryTranslatorFactoryInitiator  : HHH000397: Using ASTQueryTranslatorFactory
2019-06-02 21:20:33.900 DEBUG 22308 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] m.m.a.RequestResponseBodyMethodProcessor : Using 'application/json', given [application/json, text/plain, */*] and supported [application/json, application/*+json, application/json, application/*+json]
2019-06-02 21:20:33.901 DEBUG 22308 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] m.m.a.RequestResponseBodyMethodProcessor : Writing [Page 1 of 19 containing nl.xxxx.events.Event instances]
2019-06-02 21:20:33.923 DEBUG 22308 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] .m.m.a.ExceptionHandlerExceptionResolver : Using @ExceptionHandler public final org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity<java.lang.Object> org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ResponseEntityExceptionHandler.handleException(java.lang.Exception,org.springframework.web.context.request.WebRequest) throws java.lang.Exception
2019-06-02 21:20:33.925 DEBUG 22308 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.w.s.m.m.a.HttpEntityMethodProcessor  : No match for [application/json, text/plain, */*], supported: []
2019-06-02 21:20:33.926 DEBUG 22308 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] .m.m.a.ExceptionHandlerExceptionResolver : Resolved [org.springframework.http.converter.HttpMessageNotWritableException: Could not write JSON: failed to lazily initialize a collection of role: nl.xxxx.events.Event.schedule, could not initialize proxy - no Session; nested exception is com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException: failed to lazily initialize a collection of role: nl.xxxx.events.Event.schedule, could not initialize proxy - no Session (through reference chain: org.springframework.data.domain.PageImpl["content"]->java.util.Collections$UnmodifiableRandomAccessList[0]->nl.xxxx.events.Event["schedule"])]
2019-06-02 21:20:33.926 DEBUG 22308 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Completed 500 INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR
```

So, at some point it just says `No match for [application/json, text/plain, */*], supported: []` and wont return a nice JSON exception anymore.

Any ideas at what i'm doing wrong? initially is just want `EventNotFoundException` to result in a 404 instead of a 500. Propably in the future i'd like to add content aswell.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you try to handle RuntimeException which is too general. `public void handlePersonNotFound(RuntimeException ex)` You also don't need to extend from `ResponseEntityExceptionHandler`.

If you write an ExceptionHandler that should handle a specific exception, the handleException method needs to accept that specific exception as parameter. Also you would probably want some sort of repsonse.

```
@ControllerAdvice
public class EventExceptionHandler {
    private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(getClass());

    @ResponseBody
    @ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND)
    @ExceptionHandler(EventNotFoundException.class)
    public String handlePersonNotFound(EventNotFoundException ex) {
        logger.error("error", ex);
        return ex.getMessage();
    }
}
```

This will give a basic reponse body with the exception message and error code.